# Same route, different query but different middlewares

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on an API that has routes like this (all POST requests)

`/friends?d=onlineFriends`
`/friends?d=offlineFriends`
and on...

and this is how it's handled:

`server.js`

```js
app.post("/friends", (req, res, next) => {
  let d = req.query.d
  let path "./funcs/" + d + ".js"
  return require(path)(req, res, next)
})
```

`./funcs/onlineFriends.js`

```js
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  return res.sendStatus(200)
}
```

But the thing is, I want to use different middlewares per func, with the code above if I wanted to use a middleware it would apply to all funcs because you'd have to put it in app.post part.

I've tried following:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  middleware(req, res, next)
  return res.sendStatus(200)
}
```

but of course it results in `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.

I know you might ask "Why not use a router like /friends/online", I really can't change the client and this is how I must do it.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. For func `onlineFriends`, you use the middleware from `./funcs/onlineFriends.js`. For func `offlineFriends`, you use the middleware from `./funcs/offlineFriends.js`. So there are different middlewares for different funcs. Or what is a _func_, exactly?

Comment: Those are basically routers but under one route that are received from query, they aren't middlewares, by middleware I mean that for example, I want to use authorization check middleware for `onlineFriends` meanwhile I don't want to use it for `offlineFriends`. There's no way to do it with my current code so I'm asking for a better way to call these routers and set their middlewares.

Comment: And I don't think there's anything that's not understandable here, it's just routers but handled from one route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have middlewares `a`, `b` and `c`, you can dynamically choose a combination of them and use that to handle the request:

```js
app.post("/friends", function(req, res, next) {
  var middleware;
  switch (req.query.d) {
    case "a": middleware = [a, c]; break;
    case "b": middleware = [b]; break;
    default: return next();
  }
  express.Router().use(middleware)(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: i am now confused... because this wasn't really what i actually asked, if i want to use auth check on `onlineFriends` it would be `case "onlineFriends": m = [authCheck]` but then how would i pass the request to `./funcs/onlineFriends.js`? because thats where it sends the response

Comment: One of the middlewares could be `const c = require("./funcs/onlineFriends")`.